# WordPress How to get all the hook name of current page in Front-end

Tags: wordpress, hook, archive, taxonomy

I have created a screen in the WordPress back-end , where Admin can select Hook type ( action/filer ) and add Hook name ( As shown in the below screenshot ).

[image]

Now I want to check , if the user is visiting ANY Taxonomy/Category/Tag archive page
and if mentioned hook name is present , then do something , else do some other thing.

For eg : If I have WooCommerce Product category - T-shirt and WordPress Post Category - News ,  Now this hook `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` must be called on the T-shirt archive page , but NOT called on the News archive page.

So if I visit ANY Taxonomy/Category/Tag archive page , how do I find a List of hooks( action/filter ) called for that particular page.